# Group by and Having MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have the following query which gets me the result I want, but I can't groupe by "id_utilisateur" here's the query :

```
SELECT count(distinct d.id_dossier), p.name, u.id_utilisateur, u.superior
FROM dossier AS d
LEFT JOIN action AS a
ON a.id_dossier=d.id_dossier
LEFT JOIN CD AS cd
ON cd.id_dossier=d.id_dossier
LEFT JOIN utilisateur AS u
ON u.id_utilisateur=cd.id_utilisateur
LEFT JOIN personne AS p
ON p.id_personne=u.id_personne
WHERE d.id_dossier>0
GROUP BY u.id_utilisateur,d.id_dossier
HAVING (
    SELECT COUNT(a2.id_dossier)
    FROM action AS a2
    WHERE a2.fait=0
    AND a2.commentaire=0
    AND a2.id_dossier=d.id_dossier
)<1
ORDER BY d.date_creation DESC
LIMIT 500
```

The group by id_utilisateur is not working, i get results for the same user in multiple lines, how can I solve this?

This is the result I get vs the expected one

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it's "not working"? Please provide sample data, as well as the expected and current output. But... at first glance, you're grouping by a column in an aggregate function, and not grouping by columns that are not included in aggregate functions.

Comment: You aren't even selecting user ,did you mean name , and you aren't grouping by name so why would you not get multiple rows?

Comment: I edited the post to ad the expected the result

Comment: @P.Salmon im selecting the user's id and the name and I wanna group by id

Comment: I can't begin to describe how dull are result sets without data sets. It's like a stick without a lollipop

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` all the *unaggregated* columns in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT count(distinct d.id_dossier), p.name, u.id_utilisateur, u.superior
FROM . . .
WHERE . . .
GROUP BY  p.name, u.id_utilisateur, u.superior
HAVING . . .
```

If you explicitly want one row per `u.id_utilisateur`, then aggregate all the other columns:

```
SELECT count(distinct d.id_dossier),
       MAX(p.name) as name, u.id_utilisateur, 
       MAX(u.superior) as superior
FROM . . .
WHERE . . .
GROUP BY  p.name, u.id_utilisateur, u.superior
HAVING . . .
```

Comment: The trouble here is the subquery in having, unless i group by d.id_dossier, my query doesn't work

Comment: @Jihane . . . Use aggregation function such as `MAX()` there as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want `id_utilisateur` distinct, then you need to `group by id_utilisateur`.

your query has `GROUP BY u.id_utilisateur,d.id_dossier`, you need to change it to `GROUP BY u.id_utilisateur`.

If you need more columns on your query, then put your group by statement into inner query and then join your tables.

Comment: when i remove d.id_dossier from the group by, the query doesn't work

Comment: of course it doesn't work, that is why you first need to write your grouped query and use it as subquery.

Comment: Can you be more specific ( I have troubles understanding the group by and having  together) my thoughts are not clear about this

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have the same issue, I solved this by simply placing the subquery inside an and condition and I removed the Having clause for this specific query.